# Update specific rows from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables.

> GeneralTable

```
ID | Date      | Invoice_Number | Accno
 1 | 17/03/2016| 12334566       | 12546
```

> Client_Table

```
ID | Date      | Invoice_Number | Accno
 6 | 14/02/2016| 12334566       | 125462
```

I need to pull the Date and Accno from `Client_Table` to GeneralTable, the invoice_number is the unique field.

Result

> GeneralTable

```
ID | Date      | Invoice_Number | Accno
 1 | 14/02/2016| 12334566       | 125462
```

Comment: Store dates as dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the update-join syntax:

```
UPDATE GeneralTable g
JOIN   ClientTable c ON g.invoice_number = c.invoice_number
SET    g.date = c.date, g.accno = c.accno
```